# Linking two Tableau parameters so work in unison

Tags: parameters, tableau-api

what I'm trying to do seems simple, yet I've struggled on it for an hour.

I have two Tableau parameters that I'd like for them to change in unison.  When the user selects their desired value in the parameter MEASURES, I'd like for the parameter Format for Measure Selected to automatically change to the same value.  Once this is established, I would then hide the parameter of Format for Measure Selected.

I'm happy to share my workbook if it helps.  Thanks a mil!

-Derek

Comment: Can you use a calculated field for the Format for Measure Selected instead of another parameter?

Comment: couldn't understood your requirement, sample data would be helpful